# How can "Indem" come in the meaning "dass"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I have made a reasearch about this word and found it can mean "dass".
How could it be used in this meaning?
Please give examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could please provide a reference to a resource that indicate this to you? I can’t think of an example where "indem" and "dass" would be interchangeable.

Comment: @idmean my reference is reverso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officical "Duden" site states that this is in deed correct: [Duden: indem](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/indem_weil_derweil#Bedeutung1) **but** it can not be used to simply replace *indem* in a sentence. The example from the Duden site looks as follows:

> er hat viel Geld sparen können, indem er einen Teil der Arbeit selbst gemacht hat

which can be rewritten using *dass*:

> er hat viel Geld sparen können, dadurch, dass er einen Teil der Arbeit selbst gemacht hat

Comment: Does then "Indem" in the meaning "Darurch" fit here: Der Text geht um den fortschritt der privatschulen, indem die Nachfrage nach plätze gestiegen ist.?

Comment: Yes, but i think it is not a phrasing that would be used very often.

Comment: Sentences with "indem" contain always two parts. The left part describes a (possible) result. The right part describes the method, how this result was/will be achived.
So your sentence `Der Text geht um den Fortschritt der Privatschulen, indem die Nachfrage nach Plätzen gestiegen ist` isn't possible.